# How to projection element in array field of MongoDb collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, projection

MongoDb Collection Example (Person):

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "schools": [
                {
                    "name": "A",
                    "zipcode": "12345"
                },
                {
                    "name": "B",
                    "zipcode": "67890"
                }
            ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "schools": [
                {
                    "zipcode": "12345"
                },
                {
                    "zipcode": "67890"
                }
            ]
}
```

My current partial code for retrieving all:

```
collection.find({}, {id: true, schools: true})
```

I am querying the entire collection. But I only want to return zipcode part of school element, not other fields (because the actual school object might contain much more data which I do not need). I could retrieve all and remove those un-needed fields (like "name" of school) in code, but that's not what I am looking for. I want to do a MongoDb query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the dot notation to project specific fields inside documents embedded in an array.

```
db.collection.find({},{id:true, "schools.zipcode":1}).pretty()
```