# How to query nested list with MongoDB C# Driver projections

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Suppose I have the following data in my MongoDB:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62baf9a2851424fdb8c226f8"
  },
  "Name": "Team A",
  "TeamData": {
    "Players": [
      {
        "FirstName": "First Name A",
        "LastName": "Last Name A"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "First Name B",
        "LastName": "Last Name B"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I only want to query `LastName`. `FirstName` should be `null`.

The query projection looks like this, using dot notation:

```json
{
    "TeamData.Players.LastName": 1
}
```

How can I do this using the C# driver's LINQ support? I was able to come close with the code below, but not quite.

```cs
public IEnumerable<TeamDto> GetTeam()
{
    return _collection.Find(filter).Project(x => new TeamDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        TeamData = new TeamDataDto
        {
            Players = x.TeamData.Select(y => new PlayerDto
            {
                LastName = y.LastName
            })
        }
    });
}
```

The result is: Players array is populated, but with `null` values. I also tried my hand at `Include` and `Exclude` inside `.Project()`, also to no avail. Can anyone shed a light?

**Edit**: My question is actually very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918456/how-to-projection-element-in-array-field-of-mongodb-collection), but using LINQ instead. I know there's a way to put dot notation in `.Project`, but that's also not want I want. Thanks.

Comment: Thinking that the LINQ part is unable to convert to the MongoDB query syntax expression. Either you have to query all the fields and perform mapping in the memory, or use the dot notation that you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug (or at the very least a bit unexpected behavior) to me. Your projection actually works. I've simplified it a bit to this form:

```
var result = coll.Find("{}")
   .Project(x => x.TeamData.Players.Select(c => c.LastName))
   .ToList();
```

Actually generated request for this case is:

```
{
    "find": "coll",
    "filter": {},
    "projection": {
        "Players.LastName": 1,
        "TeamData.Players": 1,
        "_id": 0
    }
}
```

It's a bit unexpected that this level projection contains `"TeamData.Players": 1` that leads to creating result with `FirstName` even though we didn't configure it:

```
{
    "TeamData": {
        "Players": [{
                "FirstName": "First Name A",
                "LastName": "Last Name A"
            }, {
                "FirstName": "First Name B",
                "LastName": "Last Name B"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

you can check it in the shell as well via:

```
db.runCommand({ "find" : "coll", "filter" : { }, "projection" : { "Players.LastName" : 1, "TeamData.Players" : 1, "_id" : 0 } })
```

The issue with the above projection is minor and can be fixed by specifying expected projection directly:

```
var result = coll.Find("{}")
   .Project("{ 'TeamData.Players.LastName': 1 }")
   .ToList();
```

that generates just simple expected MQL:

```
{ "find" : "coll", "filter" : { }, "projection" : { "TeamData.Players.LastName" : 1 } }
```

that, in turns, returns expected document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("62d94cdeed9104ede4a35d75"),
    "TeamData": {
        "Players": [{
                "LastName": "Last Name A"
            }, {
                "LastName": "Last Name B"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but the problem is when a server has returned document, the driver also should deserialize this document to the projected output. And the projected output that you configure via LINQ expression is a simple `IEnumerable<string>`, but from the server POV it should be a list of documents (`TeamData`, `Players`), so the driver fails to do it. Since he cannot convert TeamData document to a string, it just returns `null`. You can see actually returned document via replacing a collection generic type on `BsonDocument`:

```
  var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coll");
  var result = coll.Find("{}")
       .Project("{ 'TeamData.Players.LastName': 1 }")
       .ToList();
```

So the problem is that deserialization of a server response on a driver side is incorrect and this is why your resulted items are with `null`. I would recommend creating a JIRA ticket [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/CSHARP/issues)

Comment: I ended up creating a JIRA ticket if anyone is interested in following its progress: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4265

Comment: Late update on this, but the syntax I was using was called FindFluent. Apparently it's kind of old and clunky. They suggested I used `.AsQueryable()` and from there use `.Select()` as means of projection. It worked.

Comment: it's not old and clunky. These methods use different underlying commands. AsQuerable uses `aggregate`, Find =>`find` itself.